# Wikipedia with json

Tags: php, json, wikipedia-api

```
<?php
include 'index.php';

if (@$_GET['search']) {
    $url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=".ucwords($_GET['search'])."&redirects=true";
    $url = str_replace('', '%20', $url);

    if ($data = json_decode(@file_get_contents($url)))
    {   
        foreach ($data->query->pages as $key => $value) {
            $pageID = $key;
            break;
        }
        $content = $data->query->pages->$pageID->extract;
        echo $content;
    }
    }
?>
```

I have code above about getting contents of wikipedia search result. But the problem is that if I enter wrong keyword like "makasia" instead of "malaysia",  its not showing the related results or anything, giving an error

> "Undefined property: stdClass::$extract"

Comment: There is no wikipedia page for "makasia" what do you want to happen in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that even when the search fails, the website returns valid JSON, so the call to `json_decode` returns an object (which in a boolean context is truthy), which results in you executing the code in your `if` statement, giving you the error you are seeing. Thanks to @Tgr for providing an [API reference](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Missing_and_invalid_titles) which indicates what the return data looks like when the page is missing, this code should do what you want:

```
if (@$_GET['search']) {
    $url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=".ucwords($_GET['search'])."&redirects=true";
    $url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url);

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    $found_data = false;
    foreach ($data->query->pages as $page) {
        if (property_exists($page, 'missing')) continue;
        $found_data = true;
        $content = $page->extract;
        echo $content;
    }
    if (!$found_data) {
        echo "No data for {$_GET['search']} found!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Non-existent pages (which the API can return in various cases, e.g. when listing red links on a page), foreign pages and other things which are "page-like" but not a real page and so have no page ID are indexed with consecutive negative numbers. In some cases the API needs to return real data for these (e.g. when you are listing pages which link to a given page, or you list pages edited by a user and some of those have been deleted since) which is why they are returned in the same form as existing pages, just with a `missing` flag.

Comment: @Tgr thanks for the info, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: (Which says such titles will be ignored but that's not quite true. There are a few modules which can provide meaningful information for missing titles, e.g. [linkshere](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=linkshere&titles=MediaWiki:MenuSidebar). And there are cases where the client might care about such pages even if the only information is the title, e.g. when listing internal links on a page and some of those links point to articles not yet written.)

Comment: @Tgr thanks for the info. I've updated the answer with code that seems to work OK for a limited number of searches that I tried.